# select all from members where birthday is this week

Tags: mysql

compliments of the season.. whichever season you are in. I greet you all.
I want to select all members from members table whose birthdays fall within this week Sunday to Saturday or perhaps (Monday to Sunday).
I can't seem to find info on my inquiry...that's why I am resorting to seek your help.

I used this code

```
require_once('connection/followup.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT _name, _code FROM members WHERE DAY(_dob) = DAY(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(_dob) = MONTH(GETDATE())") or die(mysql_error());
```

but it returned an error as: FUNCTION followup.GETDATE does not exist.

Please kindly help me through with this.
Thank you.

Comment: open the followup.php file and check the spellings of GetDate() function

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give you members whose DOB lies with Monday-Sunday of current week.

```
SELECT _name, _code
  FROM members
  WHERE _dob >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
   AND  _dob <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 6 DAY)
```

Comment: I have tried this
'$sql5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE _dob >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AND  _dob <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 6 DAY)") or die(mysql_error());'
$records = mysql_num_rows($sql5);
    echo 'Number of Records Found: ' .$records; but it returned 0. I have members in the database whose birthday is on 28th Feb 2015. The query returned zero (0) result.

Comment: Can you send me the DOB field data for that user. I just want to check the DateTime object.

Comment: the data type for the DOB field is DATE and not DATETIME

Comment: I also tried this:
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE  WEEK(_dob) = WEEK(CURDATE())") or die(mysql_query());
but it returned 0 records... However, I changed the date in the database table to 26th Feb which is today, and it returned 1 record.

Comment: Just to Check what is the DOB data not data type for that user. Which should be returned but is not returning.

Comment: the DOB data is: YYYY-MM-DD... that is, 2015-02-26